# Saxon EE 10.3 XSLT Error: Cannot create an attribute node (id) whose parent is a document node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

I have this source xml:

```
 <cip>
   <data>
      <typo>
         <articles>
            <article id="BM017106--">
               <lang>Lang Text(de-AT) -- BM017106--:6</lang>
            </article>
            <article id="XC01010101">
               <lang>H07V-U (Ye) 1,5mm² schwarz, PVC Aderleitung eindrähtig</lang>
            </article>
         </articles>
      </typo>
   </data>
</cip>
```

And following xslt:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:message select="cip/data/typo/articles/article[1]/@id"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I transform this with Saxon saxon9ee.jar all works fine.
When I try to transform this with saxon-ee-10.3.jar, I got: Error XTDE0420, Cannot create an attribute node (id) whose parent is a document node.
Have anyone an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Which result exactly do you get with Saxon 9 when all is "fine"? Just that message with the attribute name and/or value? Perhaps for Saxon 10, as a workaround,  output e.g. `cip/data/typo/articles/article[1]/@id!(local-name() || '=' || .)`.

Comment: There is a very old bug report https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/950 saying that Saxon 9 tried to be user-friendly by not raising that error, not sure what has changed in 10.3.

Comment: With Saxon 9 I get:
<?attribute name="id" value="BM017106--"?>

Comment: The test case https://github.com/w3c/xslt30-test/blob/master/tests/insn/message/_message-test-set.xml#L52 seems to check this, no idea why the problem did not turn up in Saxon release tests, it seems 10.0 has the behaviour of recovering by outputting the attribute node as processing instruction while 10.1 is the first Saxon release to raise XTDE0420.

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT 3.0 specification says (in §23.1):

> If the xsl:message instruction contains a sequence constructor, then
> the sequence obtained by evaluating this sequence constructor is used
> to construct the content of the new document node, as described in
> 5.7.1 Constructing Complex Content.

And 5.7.1 says that attempting to attach an attribute node to a document node is an error.

§23.1 goes on to say:

> Any dynamic error that occurs while evaluating the select expression
> or the contained sequence constructor, and any serialization error
> that occurs while processing the result, does not cause the
> transformation to fail; at worst, it means that no message is output,
> or that the only message that is output is one that relates to the
> error that occurred.

and this is what Saxon does: it outputs the error message as the content of the `xsl:message` instruction, and the transformation continues on its way.

The Note that immediately follows describes this very situation, where `xsl:message` attempts to output an attribute node. But the Note is incorrect in stating that *it is implementation-defined whether or not they are signaled to the user and whether they cause termination of the transformation* -- the normative text is clear that the error is never fatal.

So Saxon is behaving in a way that is consistent with the specification, although arguably one could do better, for example by serializing the value passed to `xsl:message` using the adaptive serialization method.

I'm not sure why it changed between releases.